# How can I send a message to all users in bot?

Tags: python, mysql, tuples

I am trying to send message to all in my bots but I can't get IDs as int. I get tuples, instead!
Code:

```
def send_msg_all_to(message):
    try:
        connect = pymysql.connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'python')
        user_id = message.chat.id
        text[user_id] = str(message.text)
        if len(text[user_id]) < 2 or len(text[user_id]) >= 120:
            raise ExpException("Error")
    except ExpException as e:
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, e)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, send_msg_all_to)
    except ValueError as e:
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Error")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, send_msg_all_to)
    except pymysql.Error as e:
        print("error in send_msg_all_to()", e)
    else:
        cursor = connect.cursor()
        query = "SELECT usr_id FROM users"
        cursor.execute(query)
        users = cursor.fetchall()
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Your message" % (text[user_id]))
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start) 
        for user in users:
            print(user)
            #bot.send_message(user, "Admin %s" % (text[user_id]))
    finally:
        connect.close()
```

I have at this moment 2 IDs in db, and this my output:

```
(1020347173,)
(130513514,)
```

I want get just all IDs without tuples, as int, and use them for `bot.send_message()`. Can you help me to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are selecting only a column, you know that you'll obtain a tuple with a single element.

So you have just to access the first element of the tuple, that is `user[0]`:

```
for user in users:
    print(user[0])
    bot.send_message(user[0], "Admin %s" % (text[user_id]))
```

Comment: I dont know why. I seems to have tried this and was getting sht. Thank you very much guy! Very very much!